# Vertical space of shaded box

Tags: framed, shapes

I use package `framed` to color background of part of the text. I put attention that `shaded` environment uses extra space before and after colored box. In search how to reduce this space, I found macro

```
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}
```

and tried it. But I got impression that this macro does not work. Is there a way to setup `\OuterFrameSep` and reduce vertical space?
Bellow I add sample code

````
\scrollmode
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper I test vertical space in shaded environment.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%

\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.94,.95}%
\begin{shaded}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{shaded}%

\begin{shaded}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{shaded}%

You can see that space between definitions 3 and 4 is larger
than space between definition 1 and 2.

\end{document}
    ```
````

Comment: Welcome to site! Please show us what you try so far with small but complete document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko , in my answer, I added sample code which shows what kind of problem I try to solve.

Comment: Try with `\begin{shaded}\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\begin{definition}...\end{definition}%
\end{shaded}%`

Comment: I tried this also. However the output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into framed.sty file and tried to reproduce their steps. In the code below you will find environment Shaped which takes less space then environment shaped

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\scrollmode
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper I test vertical space in shaded environment.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\newlength\OuterFrameSep \OuterFrameSep=0pt \relax

\newenvironment{Shaded}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep0pt \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
  \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|r}
\begin{minipage}{175pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%

\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{175pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.94,.95}%
\begin{shaded}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{shaded}%

\begin{shaded}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{shaded}%
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}


\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|r}
\begin{minipage}{175pt}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.94,.95}%
\begin{shaded}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{shaded}%

\begin{shaded}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{shaded}%
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{175pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.94,.95}%
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{Shaded}%

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{Shaded}%
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}


\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|r}
\begin{minipage}{175pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%

\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{175pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.94,.95}%
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{Shaded}%

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{definition}
Let $V$ be vector space.
The righ-side representation
$f$ of group $G$ in left vector space $V$ of columns is called
linear $G$-representation.
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{Shaded}%
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It reduces space around text in vertical and horizontal directions. I am not sure if possible to reduce only in vertical direction. If I set `\fboxsep-8pt` part of the text will not be covered by color

Comment: You can accept own answer and by this inform us that you problem is solved :-)